# Create ECDSA DER Encoded Signature

Tags: java, python, encoding, sign, ecdsa

I'm trying to create an ECDSA Signature in Java. When i create one in python it can be verified just fine in Java. But vice-versa gives me a BadSignatureException.Python is using the ECDSA library and Java is using SpongyCastle.

**Python Implementation of Signing:**

```
private_key = SigningKey.from_der(PRIVATE_KEY.decode('hex'))
private_key.sign(payload, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256, 
sigencode=sigencode_der).encode('hex'),
```

**Python Implementation of Verifying**

```
verifying_key = VerifyingKey.from_der(public_key.decode('hex'))
return vk.verify(signature.decode('hex'), payload, hashfunc=hashlib.sha256, sigdecode=sigdecode_der)
```

**Java Implementation of Signing**

```
signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "SC");
signature.initSign(this.privateKey);
signature.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
return new String(Hex.encode(signature.sign()));
```

**Java Implementation of Verifying**

```
signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", "SC");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
signature.update(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
return signature.verify(Hex.decode(expectedSignature));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `verify_digest()` and `sign_digest()` from python.
For example to verify the signature,

```
digest = SHA256.new() 
digest.update((message.encode('utf-8')))

verified = vk.verify_digest(bytes.fromhex(signature), digest.digest())
```